# HDMI monitor not recognized on Debian

Tags: linux, debian, graphics-card, hdmi, xorg.conf

Trying to connect a monitor to my Laptop (Lenovo Y560, ATI Radeon 5000 on  Debian 7.2 & k3.2.51-1) but it looks like my HDMI is not recognized at all.

```
lspci -v | grep -i vg
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 18) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Madison [Mobility Radeon HD 5000 Series] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

and my xrandr info

```
xrandr 
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS1 connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1366x768       60.0*+   40.0  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I have also installed the fglrx-driver (AMD Catalyst 12.6) by I am failing whenever I creat a xorg.conf file for this device. 
Anyone had some experience to help me in this issue?

Comment: Is it possible that you are not actually using the ATI card but the onboard one? Is the `fglrx`driver loaded? Have you set a graphics card in the BIOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a Dell Inspiron 15 (3537), I had the same problem with Debian Wheezy, and it appears that it is too old to properly deal with Intel Haswell kit. I couldn't find a way to make it work.

Upgrading to Jessie (testing, but on the verge of release) solves the problem and all the laptop hardware works perfectly.